# Cordova plugins not working with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic app built with Angular.

I am using is Calendar plugin:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

I want to create events through the plugin and save them to the local device's calendar.

I have added the plugin though:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

And I try to use it in my controller:

```
 ionic.Platform.ready(function(){onError);
    window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title, location, notes, start, end, onSuccess, onError);
 });
```

In the browser it says window.plugins is undefined and on the device the error is 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.calendar')

I have searched high and low for this, I cant seem to find a solution that works.

Any idea how to use a Cordova plugin with Ionic?

Comment: I wish I had a straight forward answer for you. I would suggest looking into "http://ngcordova.com/" to see how they wrap cordova plugins for angular apps. Also, you may want to inject the "$ionicPlatform" provider since it uses promises to ensure that app is truly ready. Ex. "$ionicPlatform.ready(..."

Comment: I looked at ngcordova but they didnt seem to have a wrapper to access the calendar, just camera etc, will look at $ionicPlatform provider now :)

Comment: ngCordova doesn't yet have a calendar plugin, but they have it listed in an issue for desired plugins. If you do any work to integrate, you should certainly contribute it. https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer was to add

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And rebuild the Platforms

If still issue not resolved, remove and add the platforms

Answer (score 8):

Cordova plugins only runs on emulators or real devices.

To test a Cordova app with the browser take a look also to Ripple Emulator (Chrome plugin), but I prefer to test on real devices.

Cheers!