# How to use (Cordova) plugin with Ionic 2 / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to use `cordova-plugin-fcm` with Ionic2/TypeScript. The wrapper FCMPlugin.js looks real simple but I'm used to Angular2/TypeScript working with import statements and don't know how to get such a plugin to work with Ionic2.

If I use the code to get a token (`FCMPlugin.getToken()`) I get:

> Cannot find name 'FCMPlugin'

When I try this [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684371/cordova-plugins-not-working-with-ionic)

I get:

> Require is not defined

Comment: do you have typescript declaration file for `cordova-plugin-fcm`?

Comment: Nope, no typings at all. Normally I can work around that somehow but this time I can not find a solution. Would be nice if this plugin would have been made similar like the native ionic-native plugins with a d.ts file. On GitHub I asked for some guidance but the issue was closed...

Comment: you could try to write a ts file for it since you said the functions pretty simple.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, looked at some of the d.ts files in ionic-native. But I think it's a bit far fetched for me, never done that and I don't know the exact details of some dependency things and the inner workings of ionic plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684371/cordova-plugins-not-working-with-ionic) is working after all. I just made the mistake to test in the browser to see if I could get rid of the error:

```
Cannot find name 'FCMPlugin'
```

This then gave me the:

```
Require is not defined
```

And I thought I was stuck. Cordova only runs on a simulator or real device but I thought I could do some testing first in the browser until I got rid of the errors (which I could not). However when running the code on a simulator or device everything is fine.

Important though is that you have to get rid of the TypeScript error "Cannot find name" otherwise it will not run. To do that without a type definition file (a d.ts file) you can just declare a variable like:

```
declare var FCMPlugin:any;
```

Just below the imports.

Then there will be no TypeScript error and everything runs just fine on a simulator/device.

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me. Still get: FCMPlugin is not defined

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with TypeScript, you can declare in your file as **@majodi** said:

```
declare var FCMPlugin: any;
```

but you will not have auto-complete.

You can also create a `fcm-plugin.d.ts` file to put in `yourAppName/src/app/fcm-plugin.d.ts` and it should look something like this:

```
declare var fcmPlugin: FCMPlugin.IFCMPlugin;

// Support AMD require
declare module 'fcmPlugin' {
    export = fcmPlugin;
}

declare namespace FCMPlugin {
    interface IFCMPlugin {
        onNotification(onNotificationCallback, successCallback, errorCallback);
        getToken(successCallback, errorCallback);
        onTokenRefresh(onTokenRefreshCallback);
        subscribeToTopic(topic: string, successCallback, errorCallback);
        unsubscribeFromTopic(topic: string, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to call fcmPlugin after check that you're on a cordova device:

```
if (platform.is('cordova')) {
    fcmPlugin.getToken(token => {
        console.log('getToken() succeed: ', token);
    }, err => {
        console.error('getToken() failed: ', err);
    });
}
```

Otherwise will have the `fcmPlugin does not exists` when you do `ionic serve`

Then you just have to call fcmPlugin and let the TypeScript auto-completion magic occur!

Comment: Having some trouble with this still. Seems the `successCallback` function get's called when a push message is received, but the `onNotificationCallback` does not get called. No errors are seen either. Any thing I can go look at to troubleshoot? Thanks!